# Fedora file permissions apache no write acces

Tags: apache, permissions, fedora, chmod, chown

I spend hours on finding out how to gain file permissions for my apache installation in Fedora 18. I did the following without any luck:

**httpd.conf (restarted it afterwards)**

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html/">
    AllowOverride all
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
</Directory>
```

**File rights on my /var/www/html folder**

```
drwxrwxrwx. 6 chris apache 4096 26 apr 22:40 .
drwxrwsrwx. 7 chris apache 4096 23 apr 09:30 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 chris apache   19 22 apr 08:37 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 chris apache   20 21 apr 17:14 info.php
drwxrwxrwx. 8 chris apache 4096 27 apr 14:58 pyro
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 chris apache  125 24 apr 00:36 test.html
```

As you can see I've even changed the permissions to 777 recursively ( with -R )

I also tried to change user to root and apache, group to user and root etc. In my version I have 2 users: root and chris.

It doesn't matter how I change this.. I still get the PHP error (in for example pyrocms backend):

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: User Warning
Message: system/cms/cache/default/simplepie/ is not writeable. Make sure you've set the correct relative or absolute path, and that the location is server-writable.
Filename: libraries/Simplepie.php
Line Number: 2040
```

Stil it doesn't seem to be pyrocms because the Laravel framework gives me the same type of error.

**Edit**
Also User and Group in my httpd.conf are set to apache

Comment: Maybe it's a typo. But you apache config refers to `/var/www/html` of which the `html` directory is not visible in your file list.

Comment: I did my ls -la command on . so . = html (so it was a typo :) )

Comment: What's the blabla part? Please provide the whole error message.

Comment: Edited the question with the full code (produced by pyrocms's framework (codeigniter). note: it's all located in my root html under the pyro folder

Comment: What's the absolute path to `system/cms/cache/default/simplepie/`. Is it writable for apache? Does it exist?

Comment: /var/www/html/pyro/system/cms/cache/default/simplepie/ it's writeable for apache

Comment: you could try to disable selinux if it is enabled and see if it will work.

Comment: Disabled it and it still doesn't change anything. I now excluded pyro and the frameworks as possible problem by creating a simple file write script: Warning: fopen(testing.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue because SELinux blocked httpd, it worked fine after this command:

```
setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

I'm on fedora 23.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. I wish these SELinux people become bankrupt and they starting begging on roads, increasing security doesn't mean you remove usability. SELinux === ShittyLinux

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that could be affecting this:

- Discretionary Access Control (DAC)
- SELinux file/content type
- user:group ownership
- apache server modules missing/misconfigured.

The fact that your server's directories have the 777 permissions would lead me to exclude **DAC** as the main reason for the errors; however, you might want to check to make sure that user(chris) is part of the `apache` group, just for good measure. Also, the httpd server reads/writes files as the `apache` *user* by default!!

Similarly, you said the errors persisted even after "disabling" **SELinux**; I'm assuming you executed `setenforce 0` or something to that effect in order to change the SELinux policy from `Enforcing` to `Permissive`.  Furthermore, if it had to do with SELinux, most of the time (if not all) you'd receive a notification about the denial, or you'd be able to see it in the logs.  Again, for good measure, check the SELinux content type of the directories/files with `ls -Z`; the content type should be `httpd_sys_content_t` or perhaps even `httpd_sys_content_rw_t`.

Lastly, the apache modules and the server configuration should be thoroughly examined--including the comments in the **httpd.conf** file--for correct options, modules, as well as order.  If all else fails, try moving those lines

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html/">
    AllowOverride all
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
</Directory>
```

to the bottom of the config file (`/etc/httpd.conf`).  The *Options* flag within that code block should be examined carefully; you can get more info on that at the [apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options).  For example, not sure if the order of things will improve/change things for you in this context, but the httpd.conf file on my Fedora system has the *Options* listed **before** the `Require All granted`.